# How do we know (from Weierstrass' theorem) that the second-order conditions are sufficient for a maximum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am reading on unconstrained optimization in $\mathbb R^n$.

The textbook just explained that for $x^*$ to be a local minimum of a multivariable function $f(x)$, we need at least $\nabla f(x^*)=0$, and $\nabla ^2f(x^*)>0$. We assume here that $f\in C^2$, f is twice continuously differentiable.

Then, the book continues with a technical detail regarding the Weierstrass theorem:

> [image]

I don't fully understand this argument, so I hope someone can explain it.

I understand that the Weierstrass Theorem here means that "If $f$ is a continuous function and $D$ is a compact set, then there exists a global minimum of $f$ over $D$".

**I am just not exactly sure how this theorem is used to conclude that the second order condition is sufficient to conclude that $x^*$ is a minimum.**

Comment: The second order conditions are sufficient by Taylor's theorem. The first order term vanishes, the second order term is positive, and the next correction (even if f is only $C^2$) is smaller than the second order term if you are close enough to the point of expansion. The one concern is about how to bound the next correction uniformly in d  so as to prove my last claim.

Comment: @Ian, Thank you. I'd still like to understand the argument based on Weierstrass' theorem though.

Comment: Their argument is a bit strange to me: look at f on a ball  of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $x_0$ and argue that the (well-defined) minimum of f on this ball is bigger than $f(x_0)$ for all sufficiently small $\varepsilon$. It seems like the extra setup of this argument does not really make the last step any easier.

Comment: Also, the second order conditions are not necessary for a minimum.

Comment: Why aren't they necessary for a minimum? you could have a saddle point with just the first order condition.

Comment: The second order condition can't tell the difference between the 1D examples $f(x)=x^3$ and $f(x)=x^4$; the former has no extremum and the latter has a minimum. It is necessary (given the regularity) to have $\nabla^2 f \geq 0$ (otherwise you have a direction to follow to reduce $f$), but that isn't sufficient.

Comment: Moreover, the $x^4$ example shows that $\nabla^2 f > 0$ is not necessary.

Comment: Could you tell how $\epsilon$ is defined in the text?

Answer (score 1):

If $x_*$ is a critical point of $f$ one has
$$f(x_*+X)=f(x_*)+{1\over2}H(X.X)+o(|X|^2)\qquad(X\to0)\ ,$$
by Taylor's theorem. If $H$ is positive definite then $H$ assumes a positive minimum $\mu>0$ on $S^2$. It follows that $H(X,X)\geq\mu|X|^2$ for all $X\in{\mathbb R}^n$. We therefore can write
$$f(x_*+X)\geq f(x_*)+\left({\mu\over2}+o(1)\right)|X|^2\qquad(X\to0)\ .$$
This shows that $$f(x_*+X)-f(x_*)>0\qquad(0<|X|<\delta)$$
for some $\delta>0$, hence $f$ has a strict local minimum at $x_3$.

Comment: The one thing that's not totally obvious is that $o(|X|^2)$ can be understood uniformly in the direction.

Comment: @Ian: This is exactly what Taylor's theorem says. For first derivative we have $f(p+X)=f(p)+\nabla f(p)\cdot X+o(|X|)$.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is: your first equation follows from the single variable Taylor theorem, but the decay rate of the $o$ *a priori* depends on the direction. It takes a little bit of actual multivariable analysis to show that it does not depend on the direction, or rather does not depend on the direction enough to obstruct a result like this.